How to get the size of the angle bisector of a triangle using the law of cosines

Question:Prove that in any arbitrary triangle like $\triangle ABC$, the size of the bisector of angle A is obtained from the following equation.
$$ AD = \frac{2AC\cdot AB\cos \frac{\hat A}{2}}{AC + AB}$$

My teacher said that it can be proved by using the theorem of cosines.
Attempts:
Since $d_a$ is the bisector of angle A, according to the property of the bisector in the triangle, it can be written
$$\frac{BD}{CD} = \frac{AB}{AC}$$
$$BD = \frac{AB\cdot CD}{AC}$$
Then I wrote the cosine theorem for the two triangles $\triangle BAD$ and $\triangle CAD$ and tried that maybe I could replace something with the above equation in these two formulas, but I didn't achieve anything.
$$BD^2 = AB^2 + AD^2 - 2AB\cdot AD\cos \frac{\hat A}{2}$$
$$CD^2 = AC^2 + AD^2 - 2AC\cdot AD\cos \frac{\hat A}{2}$$
$$(\frac{AB\cdot CD}{AC})^2 = AB^2 + AD^2 - 2AB\cdot AD\cos \frac{\hat A}{2}$$
$$CD^2 = (\frac{AC}{AB})^2\cdot (AB^2 + AD^2 - 2AB\cdot AD\cos \frac{\hat A}{2})$$
$$AC^2 + AD^2 - 2AC\cdot AD\cos \frac{\hat A}{2} = (\frac{AC}{AB})^2\cdot (AB^2 + AD^2 - 2AB\cdot AD\cos \frac{\hat A}{2})$$
$$AD = (\frac{AC}{AB})^2 - 2AB\cdot (\frac{AC}{AB})^2\cos \frac{\hat A}{2} + 2AC\cos \frac{\hat A}{2}$$


Please [edit] the question to show us just what you did, not just that "it didn't work".

Can you write out how you applied cosine theorem on those 2 triangles? In particular, pay attention to using it on $ \cos A/2$, and that $ AD = d_a$.

Welcome to MSE. I've taken the liberty of modifying your post to conform to MSE's standards. You can take a look at the changes via the "Edit" command for the future

Thanks for showing your work.
The angle bisector theorem gives us $AC \times BD = AB \times CD$ like you mentioned.
Notice that your cosine rule equations  can be written as (EG Clearing denominators in the 4th line, multiply second line by $AB^2$, etc):
$$ AC^2 \times BD^2 = AB^2 \times CD^2 = AB ^2 \times AC^2 + AB^2 \times AD^2 - 2 AB^2 \times AC \times AD  \cos \frac{A}{2}. $$
$$ AC^2 \times BD^2 = AB^2 \times CD^2 = AC ^2 \times AB^2 + AC^2 \times AD^2 - 2 AC^2 \times AB \times AD  \cos \frac{A}{2}. $$
Taking the difference of the two, we get that
$$ AD^2 (AB^2 - AC)^2 = 2 AB \times AC \times AD \cos \frac{A}{2} ( AB - AC ) $$
Dividing throughout by $ AD (AB^2- AC^2)$, we get the desired conclusion of
$$ AD = \frac{ 2 AB \times AC  \times \cos \frac{A}{2} } { AB + AC }. $$

Thank you for your answer, I understood where the second line was obtained, but I don't understand how the first line was obtained

Take your second line and multiply throughout by $AB^2$.

As you said
$$\frac{BD}{DC}=\frac{AB}{AC} \implies\frac{BD^2}{AB^2}=\frac{DC^2}{AC^2}...(i)$$
By law of cosines,
$$BD^2=AD^2+AB^2-2ADAB\cos \frac{\angle A}{2}$$
$$DC^2=AD^2+AC^2-2ADAC\cos \frac{\angle A}{2}$$
Substituting these to $(i)$, we get
$$\frac{AD^2}{AB^2} - 2\frac{AD}{AB}\cos \frac{\angle A}{2}=\frac{AD^2}{AC^2} - 2\frac{AD}{AC}\cos \frac{\angle A}{2}$$
Cancelling out $AD$ and arranging, we get
$$AD\bigg(\frac{1}{AB^2}-\frac{1}{AC^2}\bigg)=2\cos\frac{\angle A}{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{AB}-\frac{1}{AC}\bigg)$$
Simplifying this we get
$$AD=\frac{2AB×AC\cos\frac{\angle A}{2}}{AB+AC}$$
[QED]
